# Julia - Random Array

Tags: arrays, random, julia

How can I add random numbers (for example from 1 to 100) into an array using Julia language? Also, the array already has to have a defined length (for example 30 numbers).

Comment: The question is actually slightly unclear. What do you mean by 'add into'? Do you mean 'take a pre-existing vector and for each element add a random number between 1-100'. Or do you mean 'fill a vector with random numbers between 1-100'?

Comment: Your second statement is what I was looking for, but I got the answer already! Thank you for your concern!

Comment: Not quite. The answer shows two possibilities: Add random numbers to the elements of a pre-existing vector. And: create a _new_ vector of random numbers. If you already have a vector, and then want to fill it with random numbers, then that alternative has not been answered.

Answer (score 5):

If your initial vector is `v`, you can do as follows:

```
v .+= rand(1:100,length(v))
```

- `rand(1:100,length(v))` will generate a random vector of integers between 1 and 100 and of length identical to `v`'s one (the `length(v)` part), you can read the [rand()](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand) doc for further details.
- `.+=` is the Julia syntax to do an "in-place" vector addition. Concerning performance, this is an important syntax to know, see ["dot call" syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators)

---

**Update** a more efficient approach, is :

```
map!(vi->vi+rand(1:100),v,v)
```

Note: the approach is more efficient as it avoids the creation of the `rand(1:100,length(v))` temporary vector.

---

**Update** an alternative, if you want to **fill** (and not to add) the vector with random integers, is @DNS's one (see comment) :

```
using Random

v = Vector{Int}(undef,30)
rand!(v,1:100)
```

Note:

- `Vector{Int}(undef,30)` is the Julia's way to create a vector of 30 **uninitialized** integers.
- the `rand!()`function **fills** this vector with random integers. Internally it uses a for loop.

.

```
rand!(A::AbstractArray{T}, X) where {T} = rand!(default_rng(), A, X)

# ...

function rand!(rng::AbstractRNG, A::AbstractArray{T}, sp::Sampler) where T
    for i in eachindex(A)
        @inbounds A[i] = rand(rng, sp)
    end
    A
end
```

Comment: @IvanGrcic You are welcome: just check it really solves your problem and do not hesitate to ask for clarification if require

Comment: @IvanGrcic I have added some doc links, the part about ".+=" (dot call) is important to read.

Comment: Perhaps you can also mention how to fill an existing vector with random numbers: `rand!(v, 1:100)`?

Comment: @DNF, sorry  but I am not able to find the `rand!` function. What is your Julia version? Mine is  1.7.1

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have mentioned that you have to load the `Random` standard library to get that.

Answer (score 2):

the idiomatic way of doing this in one line is probably

```
julia> v = zeros(3)

julia> v .+= rand.((1:100, ))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 35.0
 27.0
 89.0

julia> @benchmark x .+= rand.((1:100, )) setup=(x = zeros(100))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 241 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  313.544 ns … 609.581 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     323.021 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   327.143 ns ±  20.920 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

    ▃▇██▇▆▆▅▄▃▂▂▁▁▁▁▁     ▁                                     ▂
  ██████████████████████████▇▇▆▆▆▅▆▆▆▅▅▅▅▁▅▄▃▅▁▁▁▃▃▁▁▁▃▄▃▃▁▁▁▁▃ █
  314 ns        Histogram: log(frequency) by time        415 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

as you can see, this version is allocation-free thanks to broadcast loop fusion